# How to create an index based on 2 columns using the UNIQUE keyword in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I know how to make it like this:

```
ALTER TABLE birdwatchers.humans
ADD INDEX human_names (name_last, name_first);
```

But how to do the same thing using the **UNIQUE** keyword (*my book asks me for that*)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use add unique:

```
Alter table birdwatchers.humans add unique human_names(name_last, name_first);
```